# Regarding Data Binding and ComboBoxes?

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, combobox, visual-studio-2015

I have a combobox with with two child's let's say ("General, unique"), and I did already bind other items to the database tables, but all of them were regular text boxes where you have to type information to get value into the table.

But I couldn't figure out how to make an option where a user can click on one of the two childs (General and unique), and when clicked it inserts the same text of the combobox child into the table.

(so same table column, can be **General** for someone and **Unique** for another)

I'm a designer not a professional coder, although most could tell that I'm not a pro by the question itself. I will be glad if someone could help me out here.

Comment: Do you want to Insert a new record in your table or updating an existing row when clicking on the combobox? Can you please give the schema of your table and some sample input data.

Comment: just adding a new record

Comment: ok, for example (Name . Gender . Type )it comes under the type column  if this person is unique or not for example.

Comment: How did you bind the other textboxes? Do you use an `SqlDataAdapter` or do you insert via plain SQL? A mock of your UI would also be helpful since I still cannot imagine how it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You simply bind the `ComboBox` in much the same way as you bind the `TextBox` controls.  For a `TextBox` it would look like this:

```
myTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", myDataTable, "DataColumnNameHere")
```

and for a `ComboBox` it would look pretty much the same:

```
myComboBox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", myDataTable, "DataColumnNameHere")
```